# How to interpret the style programmatically

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, code-behind

In my application I have to manipulate a DataGrid in code-behind (The DataGrid is also created in code-behind in runtime), and I want to set below styles for the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="DGR_Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid> <!--How to translate this-->
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Below is the my interpreted code, but I do not know how to 'translate' the **SelectiveScrollingGrid** part

```
    var myGrid = new DataGrid
    {
            RowHeaderStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRowHeader)),
            RowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow))
    };

      myGrid.RowHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed));
      myGrid.RowHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRowHeader.TemplateProperty, null));

ControlTemplate templateButton = new ControlTemplate(typeof(DataGridRow));
      FrameworkElementFactory elemFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
      elemFactory.SetValue(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(Border.BorderThicknessProperty));
      elemFactory.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(Border.BorderBrushProperty));
      elemFactory.SetValue(Border.BackgroundProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(Panel.BackgroundProperty));
      elemFactory.SetValue(Border.NameProperty, "DGR_Border");
      elemFactory.SetValue(Border.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty, true);

      var cellsPresenterFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGridCellsPresenter));
      cellsPresenterFactory.SetValue(DataGridCellsPresenter.ItemsPanelProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(ItemsControl.ItemsPanelProperty));
      cellsPresenterFactory.SetValue(DataGridCellsPresenter.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty));

      //elemFactory.AppendChild(selectiveScrollingGridFactory);

      templateButton.VisualTree = elemFactory;
      elemFactory.AppendChild(new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another `FrameworkElementFactory` with a type of `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.SelectiveScrollingGrid`:

```
...
var selectiveScrollingGridFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.SelectiveScrollingGrid));
elemFactory.AppendChild(selectiveScrollingGridFactory);

var cellsPresenterFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGridCellsPresenter));
cellsPresenterFactory.SetValue(DataGridCellsPresenter.ItemsPanelProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(ItemsControl.ItemsPanelProperty));
cellsPresenterFactory.SetValue(DataGridCellsPresenter.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty, new TemplateBindingExtension(UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty));

selectiveScrollingGridFactory.AppendChild(selectiveScrollingGridFactory);
...
```

Note that the recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a `string` or a memory stream using the `Load` method of the `XamlReader` class as stated in the documenation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks for your comments, I now defined the styles in XAML and then load it in code-behind and it is perfect for me!